# How to group products together of an ecommerce store?

Tags: clustering, k-means, text-mining, hierarchical-clustering, tf-idf

I'm working on ecommerce furniture store project. We've products like "XYZ wooden polished table", "square table", "Round table", "ABC polished table", "XYZ wooden polished sofa", "ABC polished sofa" etc. I want all the tables and all the sofas in their respective group.

I tried tf-idf and then cluster analysis. but it groups "XYZ wooden polished sofa" with "XYZ wooden polished table", because obviously they are nearer. What should I do to group all sofas, tables and all other furniture in their respective category?

Answer (score 2):

As you have seen, there is more than one good clustering. Clustering "XYZ wooden polished" is a perfectly valid cluster, and a result you must expect even from the best clustering algorithm.
So you cannot rely on clustering to do what *you* want, rather you will need something *supervised*.

Try classification. Label some examples, train a classifier and apply it to the remaining. If you notice errors, label them and add them to your training set, repeat.

Based on your input, it can learn that "wooden" and "polished" are less important for categorization than "table" and "chair". A clustering algorithm *cannot* do that.